# Add tenant claim to access token using IdentityServer 4 based on acr value

Tags: identityserver4

In my scenario a user can be linked to different tenants. A user should login in the context of a tenant. That means i would like the access token to contain a tenant claim type to restrict access to data of that tenant.

When the client application tries to login i specify an acr value to indicate for which tenant to login.

```
OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = redirectContext => {
    if (redirectContext.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Authentication) {
        redirectContext.ProtocolMessage.AcrValues = "tenant:" + tenantId; // the acr value tenant:{value} is treated special by id4 and is made available in IIdentityServerInteractionService
    }
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

The value is received by my identity provider solution and is as well available in the `IIdentityServerInteractionService`.

**The question is now, where can i add a claim to the access token for the requested tenant?**

**IProfileService**

In a IProfileService implementation the only point where acr values would be available is in the `IsActiveAsync` method when `context.Caller == AuthorizeEndpoint` in the HttpContext via IHttpContextAccessor.

```
String acr_values = _context.HttpContext.Request.Query["acr_values"].ToString();
```

But in `IsActiveAsync` i can not issue claims.
In the `GetProfileDataAsync` calls the acr values are not available in the ProfileDataRequestContext nor in the HttpContext. Here i wanted to access acr values when
`context.Caller = IdentityServerConstants.ProfileDataCallers.ClaimsProviderAccessToken`. If i would have access i could issue the tenant claim.

Further i analyzed `CustomTokenRequestValidator`, `IClaimsService` and `ITokenService` without success. It seems like the root problem is, that the token endpoint does not receive/process acr values. (event though [here](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/3.1.0/endpoints/token.html) acr is mentioned)

I have a hard time figure this one out. Any help appreciated. Is it maybe completely wrong what i am trying? After figuring this one out i will have as well to understand how this affects access token refresh.

Comment: From the documentation: acr_values allows passing in additional authentication related information for the _password_ grant type. For other flows the requests that hit the ProfileService don't include the acr values. So yes, the endpoint doesn't receive the acr values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want the user to login for each tenant (bypassing sso) makes this solution possible.

When logging in, you can add a claim to the local user (IdentityServer) where you store the tenant name:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string button)
{

    // take returnUrl from the query
    var context = await _interaction.GetAuthorizationContextAsync(returnUrl);
    if (context?.ClientId != null)
    {
        // acr value Tenant
        if (context.Tenant == null)
            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(user.Id, user.UserName);
        else
            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(user.Id, user.UserName, new Claim("tenant", context.Tenant));
```

When the ProfileService is called you can use the claim and pass it to the access token:

```
public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
{

    // Only add the claim to the access token
    if (context.Caller == "ClaimsProviderAccessToken")
    {
        var tenant = context.Subject.FindFirstValue("tenant");
        if (tenant != null)
            claims.Add(new Claim("tenant", tenant));
    }
```

The claim is now available in the client.

---

Problem is, that with single sign-on the local user is assigned to the last used tenant. So you need to make sure the user has to login again, ignoring and overwriting the cookie on IdentityServer.

This is the responsibility from the client, so you can set `prompt=login` to force a login. But originating from the client you may want to make this the responsibility of the server. In that case you may need to override the interaction response generator.

---

However, it would make sense to do something like this when you want to add tenant specific claims. But it seems you are only interested in making a distinction between tenants.

In that case I wouldn't use above implementation but move from perspective. I think there's an easier solution where you can keep the ability of SSO.

What if the tenant identifies itself at the resource? IdentityServer is a token provider, so why not create a custom token that contains the information of the tenant. Use [extension grants](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/extension_grants.html) to create an access token that combines tenant and user and restricts access to that combination only.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I have used similar method to implement subdomain/domain based multi tenancy and Tenant Selection Page based multi tenancy (using Interaction response).

Comment: Thanks a lot Ruard. I will try to work it out with your information and acceppt later. @LaliltaCode, honestly i saw your youtube video and your blog posts. I was very grateful for that information. Nevertheless i was not able to complete my task with that info, because partly i felt a little confused. Maybe later i will.

Comment: I got to work both approaches. :) Signing in with acr/tenant/claim and as well I wrote a IExtensionGrantValidator with which i can exchange the access token without tenant info for one with tenant info. But most important your answer made me think of what i really want. I see three options: (1) No tenant info in access token. When calling an api, the tenant could be a normal param. Therefore api has to check access for this tenant like i would do with fine grained access rules. (2) Login user / tenant pair (3) Login with user. Later exchange token for whatever tenant i want to access.

Comment: I think from a user perspective it should be a conscious selection what tenant i want to work with. Generally i think the extension grant is the way to go. Maybe I will be able to create a login flow with tenant selection if necessary where the user first logs in without tenant. But the client could specify maybe an acr "DoTenantSelection" and then my identity server implementation provides a page for doing that. Basically i want to extract the logic from tenant selection / token exchange to my identity server implementation. So a client could call login page or just a switch tenant page. idk

Comment: I sense there's something missing in your sample. When you do `claims.Add(new Claim("tenant", tenant));`, it seems that the `claims` variable isn't going anywhere in the `context` nor can I see where it's declared. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

To provide some code for others who want to use the extension grant validator as one suggested option by the accepted answer.
Take care, the code is quick and dirty and must be properly reviewed.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56171770/issue-a-new-claim-from-challengeresult-in-identityserver4) is a similar stackoverflow answer with extension grant validator.

**IExtensionGrantValidator**

```
using IdentityServer4.Models;
using IdentityServer4.Validation;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace IdentityService.Logic {
  public class TenantExtensionGrantValidator : IExtensionGrantValidator {
    public string GrantType => "Tenant";

    private readonly ITokenValidator _validator;

    private readonly MyUserManager _userManager;

    public TenantExtensionGrantValidator(ITokenValidator validator, MyUserManager userManager) {
      _validator = validator;
      _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task ValidateAsync(ExtensionGrantValidationContext context) {
      String userToken = context.Request.Raw.Get("AccessToken");
      String tenantIdRequested = context.Request.Raw.Get("TenantIdRequested");

      if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(userToken)) {
        context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(TokenRequestErrors.InvalidGrant);
        return;
      }
      var result = await _validator.ValidateAccessTokenAsync(userToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
      if (result.IsError) {
        context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(TokenRequestErrors.InvalidGrant);
        return;
      }

      if (Guid.TryParse(tenantIdRequested, out Guid tenantId)) {
        var sub = result.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "sub")?.Value;
        var claims = result.Claims.ToList();
        claims.RemoveAll(x => x.Type == "tenantid");
        IEnumerable<Guid> tenantIdsAvailable = await _userManager.GetTenantIds(Guid.Parse(sub)).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (tenantIdsAvailable.Contains(tenantId)) {
          claims.Add(new Claim("tenantid", tenantId.ToString()));
          var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);
          var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
          context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(principal);
          return;
        }
      }
      context.Result = new GrantValidationResult(TokenRequestErrors.InvalidGrant);
    }
  }
}
```

**Client config**

```
        new Client {
                    ClientId = "tenant.client",
                    ClientSecrets = { new Secret("xxx".Sha256()) },
                    AllowedGrantTypes = new [] { "Tenant" },
                    RequireConsent = false,
                    RequirePkce = true,
                    AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,
                    AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                    AllowedScopes = new List<String> {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    },
                },
```

**Token exchange in client**

I made a razor page which receives as url parameter the requested tenant id, because my test app is a blazor server side app and i had problems to do a sign in with the new token (via `_userStore.StoreTokenAsync`). Note that i am using [IdentityModel.AspNetCore](https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to manage token refresh. Thats why i am using the IUserTokenStore. Otherwise you would have to do httpcontext.signinasync as [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56171770/issue-a-new-claim-from-challengeresult-in-identityserver4).

```
public class TenantSpecificAccessTokenModel : PageModel {

    private readonly IUserTokenStore _userTokenStore;

    public TenantSpecificAccessTokenModel(IUserTokenStore userTokenStore) {
      _userTokenStore = userTokenStore;
    }

    public async Task OnGetAsync() {
      Guid tenantId = Guid.Parse(HttpContext.Request.Query["tenantid"]);
      await DoSignInForTenant(tenantId);
    }

    public async Task DoSignInForTenant(Guid tenantId) {
      HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
      Dictionary<String, String> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
      parameters.Add("AccessToken", await HttpContext.GetUserAccessTokenAsync());
      parameters.Add("TenantIdRequested", tenantId.ToString());
      TokenRequest tokenRequest = new TokenRequest() {
        Address = IdentityProviderConfiguration.Authority + "connect/token",
        ClientId = "tenant.client",
        ClientSecret = "xxx",
        GrantType = "Tenant",
        Parameters = parameters
      };
      TokenResponse tokenResponse = await client.RequestTokenAsync(tokenRequest).ConfigureAwait(false);
      if (!tokenResponse.IsError) {
        await _userTokenStore.StoreTokenAsync(HttpContext.User, tokenResponse.AccessToken, tokenResponse.ExpiresIn, tokenResponse.RefreshToken);
        Response.Redirect(Url.Content("~/").ToString());
      }
    }
  }
```